# Where and how to assign variable in this question

Tags: python

**Issue and What I've tried**
When I'm trying to increment the value of n by 1 why the output is coming out to be all "true". And please explain the logic of the code as well

```
 def is_power_of_two(n):  #1st line
      # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
      n = 1  #3 line
      while n % 2 == 0:  #4th line
        n = n / 2  #5th line
      # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
      if n == 1:  #7th line
        return True
      return False
      n += 1

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you left some debug code here: `n = 1  #3 line`, so you should remove it.

Also your function goes endless loop if `n == 0`. So, you can handle case `n == 0` separately

```
def is_power_of_two(n):  #1st line
    if n == 0:
        return False
    # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
    # n = 1  #3 line
    while n % 2 == 0:  #4th line
        n = n / 2  #5th line
    # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
    if n == 1:  #7th line
        return True
    return False
    n += 1

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have fixed the value of `n` at `line #3` which makes it independent of whatever you pass it via argument.

Updated Code:

```py
 def is_power_of_two(n):  #1st line
      # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
      # n = 1  #3 line delete this
      while n % 2 == 0 and n!=0:  #4th line n!=0 since it'll make it infinite loop
        n = n / 2  #5th line
      # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
      if n == 1:  #7th line
        return True
      return False
      n += 1

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```